# Is there a way to tell `next` to start at specific key?

Tags: lua, iterator, lua-table

My understanding is that `pairs(t)` simply returns `next, t, nil`.

If I change that to `next, t, someKey` (where `someKey` is a valid key in my table) will `next` start at/after that key?

I tried this on the [Lua Demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html) page:

```
t = { foo = "foo", bar = "bar", goo = "goo" }

for k,v in next, t, t.bar do
  print(k);
end
```

And got varying results each time I ran the code. So specifying a starting key has an effect, unfortunately the effect seems somewhat random. Any suggestions?

Comment: `pairs` will also iterate over the hashmap randomly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you run a program that traverses a Lua table the order will be different because Lua internally uses a random salt in hash tables.

This was introduced in Lua 5.2. See [luai_makeseed](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lstate.c.html#luai_makeseed).

Comment: Why randomise the order?

Comment: @Aubergine18, to avoid attacks that exploit quadratic or worse behavior when handling collisions in hash tables.

Comment: Are the numeric indices also randomised to protect against similar attacks?

Comment: @ChrisBeck, some positive integral numeric indices may ended up in the hash part, but these details should not matter.

Comment: @lhf: thanks for info, I did not know that. I have deleted my comment

Answer (score 2):

From the [lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next) [documentation](https://devdocs.io/lua/index#pdf-next):

> The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, *even
>   for numeric indices*. (To traverse a `table` in numeric order, use a
>   numerical `for`.)

Comment: Where exactly does this randomness come from? I'm not very good at reading C code ( http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ltable.c.html ) but from what I can see the internal index of a table isn't being constantly randomised. I could see how it would get altered if I start making changes to the table (adding/removing/updating items) but if I've not done that the internal index will be static? So is the `next` function doing the randomisation?

Comment: ...just to clarify... When a non-numeric key is added to a table, it gets hashed and that hash goes in to the internal index. So after setting some values the order might be different, but it should then remain static until any further changes are made to the table. As the internal table index is based on numeric first, then hashes, and we know where the numeric table ends (so we know where first hash is) why isn't `next` always starting with the first hash?

Comment: @Aubergine18 It's random because Lua tables are hashtables, which are  [unordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). The value that a particular key hashes to has nothing to do with the order the items are added to the table.  Now *internally* the items *do* have an order, and if you iterate the same table 10 times in a row you're going to get them in the same order every time, but that's an implementation detail and you have no control over that ordering.